# Cronjob running on a new file added

Tags: javascript, node.js, time, cron

I need some guidance about the below issue:
There are several files which uploaded to a specific folder daily. the time that the file can be added to folder is not specific and any time is possible!
The file is encoded so the job which run, decode the file. 
Now I want to know is there any method for crontab to detect any time the file has been added to folder and run the job automatically,
I don't want to specific a schedule time. because i am not sure about the time the file would be uploaded to folder.

Comment: Do you have access to run a node script to detect file creation events on the server where files are uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

it's not a task for cron.

you need the job to be run either when your watcher script registers changes in the folder file-system (if upload is done manually) or on upload request handling (if upload is done via some api)

Comment: Thanks, so i must search for watcher scripts of files.